# What is the difference in the way PageUp/Pagedown keys are handled by Terminal.app vs iTerm2.app?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm

I had an SOF question about the `ipython` REPL handling of scrolling   https://stackoverflow.com/q/65385315/1056563

> Cycle through ipython “history” with one keystroke per item even when multiple lines

I discovered there is a difference in how the `Terminal.app` handles of PageUp/PageDown:

> This turns out to be specific to the macOS Terminal app handling of PageUp / PageDown. iTerm2 instead has the desired behavior of scrolling the history using those keystrokes.

What are the differences between how those keys are handled between these App's? Can the `iTerm2` behavior be replicated  in the `Terminal.app` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with different key combinations it seems that `Shift-[PageUp/PageDn]` in `Terminal.app` has the same effect in `ipython` as simply `[PageUp/PageDn]` in `iTerm2`. I'm still not sure how/where those settings live - maybe `~/.inputrc` ?

Comment: Terminal.app (and iTerm) couldn't care less about the contents of your inputrc file, that's for shells that use readline.  What's happening is that whatever keystrokes the shell you're using expects for this function are being sent by iTerm, and not by Terminal. Look at what iTerm is sending for PgUp/PgDown, configure Terminal.app to use the same.

Comment: @MarcWilson Seems a useful explanation - feel free to make an answer on it